# iOS - Move UISearchBar programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I currently have a UISearchBar in a normal UIViewController. The SearchBar is more or less in the middle of the UIView, and when I click to enter some text, my tableView completely overlaps the searchBar, and I can't click on the clear/cancel button: I don't see the search bar anymore.
When I move my searchBar completely to the top of my view, it's perfect. But I do it with Storyboard. How can I do exactly the same programmatically? Move the SearchBar to the top top of the view.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into `UISearchController` (iOS 8+). From the Apple Docs:

> The UISearchController class defines an interface that manages the
>   presentation of a search bar in concert with the search results
>   controller’s content.

The Apple docs can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html).

If you insist on doing it manually, you could try setting up an Auto Layout constraint as follows to place the SearchBar at the top of the TableView always:

```
 [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_searchBar
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                toItem:_myTableView
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                            multiplier:1.0
                                              constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: I'd recommend getting to know AL. :) You could at least just use it for this one screen. If you don't want to use AL, check out `UISearchController`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. `[self.view insertSubview:yourSearchBar aboveSubview:yourTableView];`
2. `[parentView bringSubviewToFront:yourSearchBar];`
3. `[self.view insertSubview:yourSearchBar atIndex:0];`

Btw - All the problems with the view that jumps back and forth caused when you create them with the storyboard, so its much better to do it programmatically.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But none of those 3 options brings the searchBar to the top of the UIView...